# How do I write an Nginx location to capture everything after a question mark in a query string?

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I have a URL that looks something like this:

```
http://somedomain.loc/api/things/index?take=10&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=10&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=date_created&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=desc
```

I need an Nginx location that matches on `/api/things/index` and captures everything in the query string after the `?`. I've tried this:

```
location ~ /api/things/index?(.*) {
    return 200 $1;
}
```

But `$1` is empty. If I change this to capture the whole thing, like:

```
location ~ (/api/things/index?.*)
```

I get `/api/things/index`, but nothing after the question mark. I've tried the regex in several online regex testers and the captures appear to work, but there must be something about Nginx locations that I'm not understanding. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe try this

```
location ~/api/things/index/(.*)$ {
  return 200 $1;
}
```

**Edit from OP**
As in the comments below, turns out my problem wasn't so much the regex as it was using a capture instead of `$args`. The solution is:

```
location ~/api/things/index(.*)$ {
    return 200 $args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is no trailing `/` after `index`. I tried `location ~/api/things/index?(.*)$` and though the pattern matches, `$1` is still empty.

Comment: I think what you may need to do is this     location `~/api/things/index(.*)$ {
      return 200 $args;
    }` what comes after the "?" is considered an argument.

Comment: Boom, that's it! Thank you so much, was driving me nuts! I will edit your answer and accept it.